# Execution policy (параллельность) в clang c++ (Xcode)

Tags: c++, xcode, parallelstream

Почему в Xcode (clang) не работают execution policy (Parallelism). Речь о C++

Здесь https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#iso.2017.specific заявлено об их поддержке (P0024R2), но даже при установленной tbb компилятор ругается на отсутствие par, seq и остальных политик в пространстве имен execution? Кому нибудь удалось в Xcode использовать эти политики?

Comment: установите версию clang 11.0.0 и стандарт C++17 `https://godbolt.org/z/fEcYTGb68`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, Xcode на макбуке стоит, установлены последние обновления операционной системы и инструментов разработчика. Через Homebrew установил gnu gcc, и, например, в CLion можно сменить toolchain и указать путь к нужному компилятору, а в Xcode такое не прокатывает - пишет неподдерживаемый компилятор. Что вы имеете ввиду под установкой clang 11.0.0? Как ее установить? или все таки обновить? Стандарт C++17 имеете ввиду при сборке? Так он и так стоит 17. 20-ый тоже пробовал, бесполезно.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, у меня сейчас версия Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202). Нужно откатиться чтоли??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51290452

Comment: @AlexGlebe, при чем здесь это-то?! )))))) я все в ваших словах глубокий смысл пытался раскопать, думал я идиот, а вы оказывается мне совет как для блондинки решили дать, типа "проверить включен ли компьютер"))))

Comment: Не работают Execution policy в Xcode, и дело тут не в стандарте, а в clang.

Comment: tbb установлено (через brew), флаги -ltbb и -lpthread пробовал. Все равно ошибка: No member named 'par' in 'std::exception'

Comment: кстати, не совсем понятно, как tbb к Xcode  прикрутить. Кроме флага надо что-то делать? Путь он найдет сам?

Comment: `par` находится не в `std::exception`, а в `#include <execution>` `std::execution::par`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, ну, вы это компилятору объясните, потому что он пишет именно так как я написал: No member named 'par' in 'std::exception'

Comment: покажите ваш исходник и поспорим

Comment: со мной или с компилятором?